# How do I keep my fences from breaking?

Tags: stardew-valley

It seems I'm constantly repairing my fences after every storm.  It's seriously getting to be very annoying.  It's there something I can do to prevent this from happening or at least make them last longer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use better materials for your fence.  In order of durability: stone, iron, hardwood can all be used to build better fences.
2. Install the [Durable Fences mod](http://community.playstarbound.com/threads/storm-zoryns-mods-too-many-to-list.108756/) to have all your fences last forever.

Comment: From least to most durable: wood, stone, iron, hardwood

Comment: @Dallium is correct. Your durability order is off. Hardwood is actually the strongest, and plain wood is the weakest. Reference: [link](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Crafting#Fences).

Answer (score 4):

There are a few other things you could use as well. Barrels, Preserves and Lightning Rods. I've had some of my barrels break due to weeds or sticks but otherwise everything is unbreakable, and any of the three will serve double duty. Lighting rods are handy and they look a fence.

Comment: I loved the Lighting rod solution. I now have about 40-50 Lightning rods as a fence for my deluxe barn and Coop. Cant wait for the next Lightning Storm, So many batteries.